# hibernate can component be global ? shared by other entities?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I am new to hibernate( having c background), while going through some books and examples , I always see component embedded in class mappings. e.g.

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.mkyong.customer.Customer" table="customer">
        <!-other entity mapping -->
        <component name="Address" class="com.mkyong.customer.Address">
            <property name="address1" type="string">
                <column name="ADDRESS1" not-null="true" />
            </property>
            <property name="address2" type="string">
                <column name="ADDRESS2" not-null="true" />
            </property>

        </component>
        .
        .
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

my question is can component be global and shared by any entity ? like @embeddable JPA annotation

I am referring to example at :http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-component-mapping-example/

Comment: Are you asking if any other component can reference this component? If so, then yes.

Comment: either any other component or other entity , if yes could please provide some example ?

Answer (score 0):

Place the component in its own xml file. Only have the component like so:

```
<component name="Address" class="com.mkyong.customer.Address">
        <property name="address1" type="string">
            <column name="ADDRESS1" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="address2" type="string">
            <column name="ADDRESS2" not-null="true" />
        </property>

</component>
```

And then, whenever you want to reuse this component, simply use this line:

```
<xi:include href="your-component.xml" />
```

Be sure to add this at the top of your xml to be able to use the xi tag:

```
xmlns:xi="w3.org/2001/XInclude"
```

Or have it all in one line like so:

```
<xi:include href="your-component.xml" xmlns:xi="w3.org/2001/XInclude"/>
```